# I want this code to work only for Authors AND Contributors

Tags: user-roles

I want this code to work only for Authors AND Contributors

Please modify this code for me using

if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {

```
//Hide Menu Options in Admin Section
add_action('admin_menu','wf_cli_remove_admin_menu');
function wf_cli_remove_admin_menu()
{
    remove_menu_page('index.php');
    remove_menu_page('separator1');
    remove_menu_page('separator2');
    remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=tdb_templates');
    remove_menu_page('tools.php');
}
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_role/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, and remember, this assumes that your function was already working (I did not check that it was), and if it was, then just wrap like this:

```
<?php
        add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wf_cli_remove_admin_menu' );
        function wf_cli_remove_admin_menu() {
            $wf_user    = wp_get_current_user();
            $wf_roles   = array( 'contributor', 'author' );
            if( array_intersect( $wf_roles, $wf_user->roles ) ) :
                remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );
                remove_menu_page( 'separator1' );
                remove_menu_page( 'separator2' );
                remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
                remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=tdb_templates' );
                remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );
            endif;
        }
    ?>
```

The answer is quite simple to find... ..probably multiple answers on WPStack and then there's this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/#comment-4083